# What's the difference between workspace and (connected to server) solution?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I know I should have googled such kind of topic, but I just couldn't find a clear article.

The part I don't understand is, what is the difference if I just make two solutions on my computer mapped to the same TFS folder, or if I create two workspaces? At some level I understand there is difference between solution and TFS workspace, because a solution can be totally local and not connect to any version control. But does a workspace I created always have a solution in my local computer? If so, I really don't understand why I should have such a workspace.

Another thing I don't understand is, after I open one solution in VS, I can still switch to another workspace (which is always in another solution if my previous question is yes) in Team Explorer and Solution Explorer. What is the idea behind that? I find such operation confusing.

BTW I am actually not sure whether workspace is the thing I am looking for. What I want to do is: I have multiple assignments on the same software project of the same development branch. So I want to have the ability to be working in one assignment without affecting other ongoing assignments. Previously I had to either create a new solution (I actually did so when I needed to work with a different branch), or just simply shelve the changes to one assignment -> undo pending changes -> do changes to other assignments. I was told the workspace is the solution, but after reading some articles, I still have no clue how to use it.

Comment: here I am in 2017 (nearly 2018) and I am still quite unsure the best workflow for handling task management in VS in the way you describe. I found this question because I have been searching about, and experimenting with using the workspaces feature to no avail.

I wonder if part of the issue is due to my obligation to use IIS Express, but it seems to me that I can not work on two tasks in separate workplaces, while debugging those separate changesets in browser locally, without switching my entire solution. It the age of branch based workflow, I can't believe I am still required to shelve.

Comment: If you have found a workflow that solves for the issues you were having when this was posted, I'd love to hear how you were able to manage working locally between multiple sets of pending changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TFS workspace defines what change control files and folders and mapped to local files and folders (and thus is specific to the combination of user and machine).

A VS solution defines a collection of projects and their mutual dependencies worked on as a unit (usually to create a single software product of one or more executable files and libraries).

This these concepts are orthogonal. A workspace can contain many folders each within a separate folder.

Unless you want to be able to work on multiple different things at once that you need to check in separately I would strongly suggest avoiding multiple workspaces until you are more comfortable with change control. While multiple workspaces is a powerful approach in certain use cases, it does add complexity.

Equally I would suggest avoiding having a single folder containing multiple solutions, this is not the way VS operates by default and needs careful management to avoid problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry but I am not sure I understand the concept "folder" in your answer. "A workspace can contain many folders each within a separate folder". "Equally I would suggest avoiding having a single folder containing multiple solutions". Does it mean the local computer "file folder" (if so I don't understand the scenarios you described), or does it has some special meaning in TFS/VS terminology? And in fact "to be able to work on multiple different things at once that you need to check in separately" is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: I guess I can achieve that by making multiple local solutions mapped to the same TFS folder, each corresponding to one task I have. But I just don't know what the workspace is used for, if I can do what I described without even knowing the existence of workspace

Comment: @tete locally folder == directory. In TFS it is a data structure that maps (via a workspace) to a local directory. Multiple solutions in one folder (ie. multiple `.sln` files in one directory) can be achived, but you cannot directly create them in VS: this is a strong indication that they may not work consistently.

Comment: @tete re. your second comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. "Solution" is a VS thing, and has no special meaning in TFS (it is just a text file). If you want to work on multiple takss (assignments) concurrently you would be best having the same folder in TFS mapped to multiple locations on you working machine via different workspaces (so you can checkin one set of changes without impacting others) however *this is not good practice*. Better to have smaller tasks (perhaps each contributing to a different master task) and work on one at a time to completion. Also saves merging.

Comment: Second the "strongly avoid" multiple workspaces until you're comfortable with one. .

Comment: @Richard thanks for your reply. Now my understanding is workspace and solution are different things from different angles, even though in reality you have to have one local solution assigned to one workspace IF you want to modify you code AND IF you want to do the modification in VS. It makes sense to me. But I still think it is confusing to have the Team Explorer view available for all workspaces when you already opened one solution assigned to one specific workspace. It is so easy to make mistake with wrong workspace. (I guess it is one of the reasons you suggest avoid multi workspace)

Comment: @Richard And regarding to avoiding using multi-workspace, I am not comfortable with current VS arrangement as I mentioned on my previous comment, but I guess it is more like a SW development methodology, that it is quite common to have multi tasks and each of them can't be done in hours. So I can't really start one task only after I finish another. I guess this case is not rare in small companies as ours. I don't think this development process is wrong, but just the tool is not friendly to it.

Comment: @tete You may be better considering using *[Shelve sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx)* than multiple states. A shelve set allows one to save the current changes (and associated work items) to a named set on the server optionally undoing those changes in the local workspace. The shelvesets can then be reapplied later to the same or a different workspace. Thus they can be used to "put aside" work in progress to switch focus or to transfer it to another system or even user.

Comment: @Richard actually I was using "shelve set" function to manage between tasks until recently. But I find it quite clumsy when I have many changes, especially when those changes involve add/remove files or modification of files which are modified in other shelve set. TFS frequently tells me the unshelve can't be done because of some conflicts (I think the key "problem" with shelve/unshelve is you are doing the parallel but sometimes overlapping change in only ONE solution/workspace). Our SW development process is of course not optimal but I still don't think this requirement is bad :)

Answer (score 0):

These are getting a bit old now (as they don't talk about Local or Server workspaces and Public or Private settings) but I wrote a couple of blog posts about workspaces that might help:

1. [Workspace 101: An introduction to TFS Workspaces](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000333.html)
2. [Workspace 101: Working folder mappings](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000334.html)

Also, the Version Control chapter of the [Professional Team Foundation Server](http://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/home?ie=UTF8&camp=213733&creative=393193&linkCode=shr&tag=woodweb03-20) book should help.

Comment: Thanks for your articles. So am I safe to say that if I want to do multi-tasks at the same time and don't want the changes to one task to affect other tasks, I should then have multi workspaces? And in that case, one solution corresponds to one workspace? BTW I find it extremely confusing that I can open one solution(workspace) but do some operation to another workspace(not code modification but e.g file operation). At some point I understand that solutions and workspace don't mean the same thing even if TFS is used. But still it is easy to make a mistake to modify the wrong workspace.